# Не могу вызвать метод math.min

Tags: intellij-idea

Я очень слабо разбираюсь в intellij idea. Хотел вызвать метод math.min, нажал что-то что предлагала идеа и в итоге сейчас в контекстном меню не вызывается этот метод, то есть пропал из меню и когда пишу min он не появляется. Как его вернуть?

Comment: Покажите код класса

Comment: А зачем код? Он пропал из меню, я походу сбросил его из настроек(когфигурации)

Comment: А как Вы предполагаете мы поймем в чем проблема? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Закройте её и удалите папку конфигурации из каталога пользователя (и .idea из проекта). И всё будет как с завода)